# How to Highlight all the zeros in the table with vba

Tags: vba

I have a table that has a header and the first column has student names. the rest of the table has student scores.

I need to highlight all the cells with zeros in them so far this is what i got

```
Sub HighLightZeros()
Dim region As Range
Set region = ActiveSheet.Range("a1").End(xlDown)

If region.Value = 0 Then

region.Interior.Color = vbYellow
Else
region.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
End If

End Sub
```

Also I have to make the macro so that when I add more scores to end on the table that it still highlights all the zero values. I am having trouble in figuring out how to select the entire table.

Comment: Did you consider using conditional formatting?

Comment: I have to use vba only to figure this out

Comment: While I understand the educational context, one of the skills in coding is to learn when not to do coding. The technically correct response is to say - the application has built in functionality to do this work and the most efficient way is to use that functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could like follows

```
Sub HighLightZeros()
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        With .Resize(, .Columns.Count - 1).Offset(, 1) 'reference all "used" cells except column A ones
            .Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone ' uncolor referenced range
            .Replace what:=0, lookat:=xlWhole, replacement:="XXX" ' replace 0's with "XXX"
            .SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Interior.Color = vbYellow ' color referenced range cells with text content in yellow
            .Replace what:="XXX", lookat:=xlWhole, replacement:=0 ' replace "XXX"'s with 0
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

---

trying to build up some working code from your *skeleton* in the question, it could be

```
Sub HighLightZeros2()
    Dim region As Range, cell As Range
    Set region = Range("a1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))

    For Each cell In region
        If cell.Value = 0 Then
            cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        Else
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

but it'd scan the first column cells only

Comment: Wow this works but I am still doing a beginner class in vba and havent yet done anything like this. If you could look at my code and let me know what I can change to get the same result would be great.

Comment: done, There must be a simpler way to do this rather than changing the number into text highlighting the text cells and then changing the text into numbers. Can we get the same result by using an if statement?

Comment: see edited code where I added a code built up from yours. but it'd scan only column A cells. So you may want to adapt it to suit your needs. and one thing: simpler doesn't always stand for efficient...

Comment: Hmm i see what you did there, I think I know how to select the entire range of columns. Let me try this out and get back to you then I will post the results. Thanks again

Comment: Okay so I got it to work on the other columns by doing this

'Sub HighLightZeros()
    Dim region As Range, cell As Range
    Set region = Range("B2:N502", Range("B2:N502").End(xlDown))

    For Each cell In region
        If cell.Value = 0 Then
            cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        Else
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        End If
    Next
End Sub'

Answer (score 0):

This is less efficient than @DisplayName's method but another way. Assumes table is an actual table (List object. Created with Ctrl + T)

```
Option Explicit

Sub HighlightZeroes()

    Dim table As ListObject
    Dim currentCell As Range

    Set table = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1") 'change as required

    For Each currentCell In table.DataBodyRange

         With currentCell

            .Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
            If .Value = 0 Then .Interior.Color = vbYellow

         End With

    Next currentCell

End Sub
```